# Unity Deployment on Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: ubuntu, unity-game-engine, port, digital-ocean, multiplayer

I made a unity Multiplayer Game similar to POKER Game. 
I have the game running on local machine with unity's default local IP and port.
I am able to create room,players can join room.

I am using Master Server Kit for managing Server side on local.

From my understanding i have use my droplet's IP and Some open Port to access the server.

But as i don't have server side understanding, i would be very thankful if some can give me reference material on how to :

Open port in digital ocean Ubuntu 16.04.
Where to put my ZoneServer.exe,RoomServer.exe,and WorldServer.exe in filesystem?
How can I access suppose ip:port/Zoneserver.exe
So far, I have tried numerous solutions, but none worked.

Usually, I would create a game and test it on Local Machine only.

Answer (score 1):

The file extensions `.exe` suggest that you have Windows binaries that you're trying to run.

However, Digital Ocean only supports Linux VMs so you will have to find another hosting provider that supports Windows VMs.

Alternatively, you can also build your server for Linux, [here](http://www.spelltwinegames.com/masterserverkit/documentation/setup/#demo) is more information how to do it.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unity-deployment-on-digital-ocean-droplet?comment=70021